# RMagick - convert file to another format without saving to disk

Tags: ruby, rmagick, image-conversion

I'm trying to convert a file to a specific format so I can to_blob it. I know the technique of saving to disk and specifying the extension to convert it to another format, like this:

```
img.write("another_filename.jpg")
```

I'd like to not have to touch the disk during the conversion.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the format when calling `to_blob`. From the [fine manual](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#to_blob):

> **to_blob** `img.to_blob` *[ { optional arguments } ]-> string*
>
> [...]
>   No required arguments, however you can specify the image format (such as JPEG, PNG, etc.) and depth by calling the format and depth attributes, as well as other `Image::Info` attributes as appropriate, in a block associated with the method.

So you can say things like this:

```
png_bytes = img.to_blob { |attrs| attrs.format = 'PNG' }
```

Yes, the interface to `to_blob` is a bit odd but the strange interface is just part of the fun of working with ImageMagick.

You can also use the [`format=` method](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/imageattrs.html#format) before calling `to_blob`:

```
img.format = 'PNG'
png_bytes  = img.to_blob
```